# Не отображаются опции динамического списка q-select

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar.js

Есть список `q-select`, который заполняется опциями через атрибут `:options`. Опции заполняются через PHP-шный метод (`temp` - для хранения изначальных опций):

```php
$this->options['producer'] = $this->temp['producer'] = $arResult; //Наполнил через запрос
```

Попытался сделать фильтрацию пользователем и теперь select выглядит так:

```html
<q-select
   class="q-pa-md"
   dense
   options-dense
   use-input
   label="Производитель"
   v-model="producer"
   data-cid="producerSelect"
   :options="options.producer"
   @filter="filterProducer"
/>
```

Теперь же мне нужно выводить лишь те значения списка, подстрокой которых является введенное пользователем значение. Обработка фильтрации - метод `@filter`:

```js
filterProducer (val, update) {
   if (val === '') {
      update(() => {
         this.options.producer = this.temp.producer
      })
      return
   }
   update( async () => {
      let options = await getOptions(val)
      this.options.producer = options.producer
   })
}
```

Таки все нормально даже работает, однако, если я начну убирать кнопкой `backspace` значения, то в какой-то момент `select` покажет не все опции (см. рис.), но если начать перемещение по элементам списка, используя стрелки на клавиатуре, то все элементы появятся. Не могу понять, почему исчезают элементы, и как это решить.

Метод getOptions:

```
getOptions($val)
{
        Loader::includeModule('crm');
        $result = array();

        $obCompanies = \Bitrix\Crm\CompanyTable::getList(array(
            'select' => array(
                'TITLE',
                'ID',
            ),
            'filter' => array(
                '%TITLE' => $val,
                'UF_CLIENT_TYPE' => '94',
            ),
            'limit' =>15,
        ));
        while ($arCompanies = $obCompanies->fetchRaw()){
            $result[] = array(
                'label' => $arCompanies['TITLE'],
                'value' => $arCompanies['ID']
            );
        }

        return Result::json(array(
            'producer' => $result
        ));
    }
```

[image: Изначальный список]

[image: Ввели значение]

[image: Начали стирать]

Как видно на скриншотах, после введения информации и последующего стирания не отобразился элемент `"test 132"`

Comment: у вас в if не там return стоит и не хватает фигурной скобки. То есть у вас по факту весь код в условии находится

Comment: Обновил актуальный код

Comment: кода бы побольше, а то у вас во втором update не очень понятно что происходит, getOptions(val) зачем. Вам просто нужно применить метод filter к данным

Comment: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select/

Comment: Это по сути и есть весь код. Функция getOptions(val) просто возвращает данные, которые нужно вывести (чтобы выводились только те опции, которые содержат подстроку введенную пользователем - val). Далее она берет vue-object и пихает его в :options. Все работает штатно до начала удаления символов.
По поводу кода: какую ещё информацию уточнить?
Документацию читал, потом полез сюда. Quasar v.1.22.9

Comment: метод filter не нужен, так как всю выборку производит отдельный скрипт с методом getOptions()

Comment: getOptions(val) на бэк запрос отправляет? код этой функции можно выложить

Comment: Обновил. На самом деле, он нормально возвращает значения с бэка (делаю на битрикс), проверил возвращаемые данные и всё хорошо, кажется, это дело имено на стороне vue

Answer (score 0):

Возможная причина в том, у вас статический массив перезаписывается динамическим

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

аттрибут :options как раз же нужно "забиндить" тоесть писать именно с двумя точками впереди, может в этом причина?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил, что неккорктно скопировался код. Обновил